# oracle sysdate in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sysdate

I tried to use SYSDATE in where clause in my trigger in oracle database but the code throw "ORA-01722: invalid number" exception.

```
 SELECT 'ATT' || '-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') || '-' 
       || LPAD((SELECT TO_NUMBER(COUNT(*)) 
                FROM  ATT_REQUEST_DATA 
                WHERE REQID like ('ATT-' + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') + '-%')) + 1, '4', '0')
```

Do you know, how should I repair it?

---

here is definition of table

```
CREATE TABLE ATT_REQUEST_DATA
( REQID VARCHAR2(50),
  REQ_SUBID NUMBER,
  FLAG_ID NUMBER,
  DATE_FROM DATE,
  DATE_TO DATE,
  CREATED_DATE DATE,

  CONSTRAINT ATT_REQUEST_DATA_PK PRIMARY KEY (REQID, REQ_SUBID)
);
/
```

here is an example of inserted data

```
INSERT INTO ATT_REQUEST_DATA (FLAG_ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, CREATED_DATE)
VALUES (2, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
```

and here is the error output

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   ORA-06512: at "PD.ATT_REQUEST_DATA_TRG_ID", line 4
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PD.ATT_REQUEST_DATA_TRG_ID'

---

And here is whole trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ATT_REQUEST_DATA_TRG_ID
BEFORE INSERT ON ATT_REQUEST_DATA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.REQID IS NULL) THEN

        SELECT 'ATT' || '-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') || '-' || LPAD((SELECT TO_NUMBER(COUNT(*)) FROM  ATT_REQUEST_DATA WHERE REQID like ('ATT-' + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') + '-%')) + 1, '4', '0')
        INTO   :NEW.REQID
        FROM DUAL;

        SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATT_REQUEST_DATA WHERE REQID = :NEW.REQID) + 1
        INTO   :NEW.REQ_SUBID 
        FROM DUAL;


    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Please add structure of `ATT_REQUEST_DATA` table, some sample data and expected output. You don't need to use `TO_NUMBER` for `COUNT(*)`. `COUNT` already gives you a NUMBER.

Comment: Add it it question please. Don't add as comments. Also add some sample data and output that you want

Comment: The code in your trigger doesn't match the original SQL you posted

Comment: Sorry, I tried to solve it in other way and it was some another version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the use of SYSDATE that's causing your problem

Your code has a couple of oddities. Firstly there's this gem: `TO_NUMBER(COUNT(*))` . `count()` returns a number so there's no need to cast it; fortunately Oracle is clever enough to know this, so that's not the source of the ORA-01722 error.

No, that is because of these operations: `('ATT-' + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') + '-%'))`. In Oracle SQL `+` is an arithmetical operator: the SQL engine thinks you want to **add** `'ATT-'` to `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')`, and we cannot do addition on strings. To fix this, replace `+` with the concatenation operator `||` :

```
('ATT-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') || '-%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with 
  p  as (select 'ATT' || '-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY') || '-' pattern from dual )
  , cnt as (  
    SELECT pattern, COUNT(*) cnt 
    FROM  ATT_REQUEST_DATA cross join p 
    WHERE REQID like pattern || '%')
  , res as (select pattern || LPAD(  cnt + 1, '4', '0') from  cnt )
select * from res;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c971a6/5

Note, i used WITH clause to factor out sub parts of ur SQL into smaller chunks to make debugging easier. u can safely recombine this into a single Select without the WITH clause